# How to prevent round-off error with Math.sin(Math.PI)?

Tags: javascript, trigonometry

When evaluating `Math.sin(Math.PI)` in JavaScript, the result is `1.2246063538223773e-16` rather than `0`. I suppose this is due to the limited precision of the JavaScript `Number` and limited precision of the sinus algorithm.

How could one prevent these round off errors? Would it help to use a BigNumber type with higher precision, and a higher precision sinus algorithm? Or would that just give you a smaller round-off error but still an error?

Comment: You will always get an error because `PI` is not a finit number. You need to think over if the given error is really a problem for you or not.

Comment: @t.niese: the sinus of PI **is** 0. That's basic math...

Comment: @Cerbrus In theory yes. But only if you use all digits of PI ;) So either `Math.sin`  is wrong when you don't use all digits of PI, or you don't get exactly 0. Furthermore you can't display all numbers with floating points, but thats another problem.

Comment: @t.niese I think you hit the nail with that: `PI` itself already has a round off error. I suppose the only real solution is symbolic computation instead of numeric.

Comment: @JosdeJong It always depends on what you want to do with the result. Floating point calculations always have an error, because you can always get a number as result that can't be described exactly by the `IEEE 754` representation. Thats one reason you  e.g. should not use `==` with those numbers. There are different ways to compare using a threshold, but which technique is the best depends on what you want to do with that numbers.

Comment: I'm working on a maths library [math.js](http://mathjs.org), and people are indeed expecting `sin(pi) == 0` to return `true`. I know floating points have round-off errors and comparisons with them are dangerous, but most people don't and they can easily conclude that the library is broken :)

Answer (score 4):

I use [Number.EPSILON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/EPSILON) to sort out rounding errors.  This is mostly supported but the linked page has a polyfill for IE

```
 var sinTheta = Math.sin(theta);
 if (Math.abs(sinTheta) < Number.EPSILON) {
   sinTheta = 0;
 }
```

Comment: How to deal with `Math.sin(2 * Math.PI)`?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Math.sin(Math.PI).toFixed(2)`, the parameter of `.toFixed` is the precision you need.

Unfortunately, IEEE 754 is not perfect and also the memory is limited... The same happens when you: `0.1 + 0.2 == 0.30000000000000004`

You should be aware that the result of `.toFixed(precision)` is string, so you may need to:

```
parseFloat(Math.sin(Math.PI).toFixed(2));
```

Comment: Yes, that would hide the round-off error. But this doesn't allow calculations close around 0, PI, 2*PI, etc (say `Math.sin(0.001)`).

Comment: Yes, agree but unfortunately I don't think there is better alternative.

Comment: If you increase the precision you can do `Math.sin(0.001)` and it'll work, for example, I'm using a precision of 5.

Comment: Have a look at the definition of Number.EPSILON https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/EPSILON

Comment: Using String operations to deal with floating point errors is very slow, and has even WORSE precision than floating point.